# What keeps India from reacting more aggressively to Pakistani or Chinese infringement of its borders?

Tags: india

The government of India has in the past stated that its territorial sovereignty must be respected.  To wit:

- (Example)

Despite this, both Pakistan and China have made aggressive moves, such as:

- Example
- Example

What prevents India from taking diplomatic or military action in these situations?

Comment: What's "China's border strategy"? Is this to do with what's happening in the South China Sea?

Comment: Because India isn't willing to risk open warfare against China if they follow through on their "or else...".

Comment: @NeeleshPandey This question seems to be asking: "Why is India passive when China does not respect its soverignity?"  It would be helpful if you could provide specific instances of border incursions or other infringement.

Comment: @affable, that's what I meant to ask

Comment: I'm going to do a template, but like I said, you need to put in th eexamples

Comment: Question is impossible to answer if the declarative aspects of it are not sourced.

Comment: An on-going border skirmish is exactly the kind of healthy diet that makes today's China strong. **Small skirmishes make great generals.** A soldier who's never seen battle is no better than a toy soldier. China hasn't fought anyone for more than three decades; it's military is no better than a domesticated tiger.

Comment: China should regularly send platoon sized units across the border to destroy military targets or just to take on a greater number of enemies for kicks. But the real aim is for training purpose. If they die so be it, if they come back alive, they will be candidates for the next generation military leadership.

Comment: A general who has not seen battle for 30 years should know his position. Not only that he should make way asap, but also that his opinion on who should be promoted should not be taken seriously.

Comment: India is desirous to make a career as American lackey; China badly needs target practising. Win-win.

Comment: China is sick with industrial surplus. A little war will do China just good.

Comment: India is an excellent place to expend outdated munitions, be it short-range missiles or 7.62s made in the 50s. It is also a perfect place to test new ones or just to prove a concept. The most perfect thing is that China can do whatever it likes to India with an absolutely clear conscience.

Comment: A generation that has never see battle is as vulnerable as a generation of weakling; a nation that hasn't seen war for decades is as sick as the one who suffered humiliating defeat.

Comment: But the next war will involve surprisingly few casualties. It will destroy all of India's high value targets: submarines, warships, missile launchers, war planes and nuclear research centres. That's all.

Comment: Indian politicians will not be deterred by the loss of lives of their soldiers, who are just brainwashed sons of the poor, but they do have a fear of loss with regard to their expensive military hardware. Complete destruction of India's nuclear capabilities with precision guided conventional weapons will knock the Indians back to their senses.

Answer (score 2):

India, Pakistan and China are also members of the "Nuclear Club"--aka nations with nuclear weapons. Most nation states are neither suicidal nor insane. The threat of mutually assured destruction tends to work, at least in the short term, when dealing with lucid, sane, reasonable people.

Comment: This is so ironic that same MAD concept doesn't deter China and specially Pakistan from trying to make inroads into Indian territory. So you didn't answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

India have shared our concern to Xi Jinp in his visit to India. China's military told to follow Xi Jinping's instructions regarding backing off from Indian border.

[read](http://indiatoday.intoday.in/story/china-military-told-to-follow-xi-jinping-instructions/1/384200.html)

Comment: But today only, China again did the same thing,  they again crossed the border

Comment: @NeeleshPandey Are you referring to Xi Jinping's visit, which was certainly an instance where a Chinese crossed the border to India? :) If you have something else in mind, please provide credible evidence.

Answer (score -1):

When it comes to Pakistan, I guess it will be an understatement to say that Indian response is passive. Both infiltrators as well as the Pakistan army backing them have suffering casualties on daily basis. And it getting even more aggressive now. Without even going into the rhetoric or cross border surgical strike, its pretty evident that India is giving a befitting reply. Now taking it to next level would mean a fifth war amongst the arch rivals. With possibilities of it turning into a nuclear conflict India exercises certain restraints.

Now when it comes to China, yes its true India's response is passive but it a clever tactic and I quote PM Modi' recent statement "Not a single bullet has been fired between the two nation". I guess that pretty much sums it up. We are competing economies with both aggressively upgrading their arsenal and time again due to the border sharing some conflicts do arise. India however has positioned itself well to handle the heat from the dragon. After all its not like we are in 1962 any-more.

Comment: -1 You must source your statements, it's not enough for you to assert that PM Modi has said something, you **must** link to it. Also don't make references like 1962 without giving an explanation of what it is referencing e.g I'm assuming you are referencing the [Sino-Indian War](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sino-Indian_War) but this is not clear. Also self references like "we" should be avoided in favour of 3rd person references such as "India"